# How to fix: sticky position behaving like fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a sample website for a possible client and I have gotten this to work before but can't replicate it. Basically, I have the title div which is the blue box, I have the header/menu bar which should be right under it. And finally, I have the large image resembling the rest of the website that is below the header. I want the menu bar/header to (when the site loads) begin positioned just below the Title div. And as you scroll down to browse the website it moves up until it reaches the top of the site and then it works as a fixed position, preferably I'd like to accomplish this using the CSS `position: sticky;`

What I have in the following script in the CSS seems to make the header act as a fixed position rather than anything else. Even if I offset it using `top: 90px;` I have tried having a div surround the entire page except for the title and placing the header inside to use as a sort of container, didn't work. I've tried not using an encompassing div at all. Nada...

CSS:

```
#sticky {
position: sticky;
background: orange;
top:90px;
z-index: 50;
width: 100%;
height:50px;
}
```

---

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="title">
    </div>
    <div id="sticky">
    <ul id="ulHeader">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Find Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="image">
    <img src="images/tacos.jpeg">
    </div>
```

I don't receive any error messages and I expect, using this code, for the header/menu bar to begin `90px` from the top of the page and as you scroll for it to get stuck at the top once you scroll far enough. Unfortunately what ends up happening is the header simply stays `90px` from the top consistently like a fixed element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the top to be 0px so that it sticks at top of the page

```
#sticky {
position: sticky;
background: orange;
top:0px;
z-index: 50;
width: 100%;
height:50px;
}
```

You can also have a look at this [example](https://codepen.io/Wulfor/full/bPoKQQ)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it failed to work and basically just moved to the top and acted like it was a fixed element, I ended up copying your code where it needed to be replaced and it worked! I don't understand why though, could you help me understand the following?:
How does the header bar actually know to start below the title

And how do I go about positioning the sticky element/div where I want in future situations? 

Thanks for the answer, I'd like to better understand to help me be able to use this in the future.

Comment: Header bar is below title because header div is written after title div.As for the positioning of sticky elements the top,left,right and bottom properties are used to define the place where you want your sticky element to stick.If you want help in your code share your whole code on codepen.